# Context menu with click handlers

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

I'm trying to learn how to structure my jQuery code better. I'm only about a week into jQuery so if something looks way off please tell me. I'm attempting to use object literals and it appears to work ok, but I am wondering if there is possibly a better way to structure my code.

```
var application = {
    wrapper: $('#wrapper'),
    addButton: $('#add'),
    init: function() {
        this.addButton.click(this.buttonHandlers.clickHandler);
        this.wrapper.on("contextmenu", "#wrapper div", this.buttonHandlers.contextMenuHandler);
    },
    buttonHandlers: {
        clickHandler: function(e) {
            console.log("clickyHandler");
        },
        contextMenuHandler: function(e) {
            console.log("right click");
            return false;
        }
    }
};

application.init();​
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't scale if you entire application is one large object.

If you seperated it into multiple objects

```
var application = []

application.push({
  wrapper: $("#wrapper"),
  init: function () {
    this.wrapper.on(bla, this.foo)
  },
  foo: function () {

  }
})

...

applications.forEach(function (app) { app.init() })
```

it will becomes significantly more maintainable.

You may also want to look into techniques for spreading application infrastructure across multiple files. For example [ncore](https://github.com/Raynos/ncore) uses browserify for it's module system, and uses dependency injection and an expected object format to stitch multiple "modules" together.

Comment: Note note that Array.forEach is not going to work in IE8 or lower. Personally I recommend underscore.js for a collection-processing library

Comment: Array#forEach is part of ES5, if you want to support legacy browsers use a legacy browser support technique of choice. I recommend using the ES5 shim, as for underscore, it's kind of useless given ES5

Comment: Absolutely true (I like modernizr), but common, how many of us are in a position where we can not support IE8? I'm just saying the incompatibility should be mentioned

Comment: I disagree on wasting my time mentioning legacy support techniques on throw away example code. If the question was "how to iterate over an array in a cross browser manner" then sure, if the question is a high level thing, then no

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an anonymous function around everything, so you don't have to type `this` all the time:

```
(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
  var $addButton = $('#add');

  function init() {
    $addButton.click(clickHandler);
    $wrapper.on("contextmenu", "#wrapper div", contextMenuHandler);
  }

  function clickHandler(e) {
    console.log("clickyHandler");
  }
  
  function contextMenuHandler(e) {
    console.log("right click");
    return false;
  }

  init();

})();
```

This way everything is hidden inside the big anonymous function. No code from the outside can access the objects. Depending on whether or not you want such a “black box behavior”, this can be good or not.